# ethernet testing with Android Tablet 4.2.2

Tags: ethernet

I am planning to develop a Ethernet test tool on android tablet. I know that it's better to run at wireless at Android. But I need the following information.

Does Android has driver support for Ethernet Cable
Does android has driver to access ethernet on USB port?

I know that this is not a programming question. But I found nowhere else to get the answers for these queries. Please don't consider this as off-topic. It would be helpful for me, if I can get the details.

Comment: As helpful as it might be, it's off topic here. Hint: It is **not** off topic in SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the documentation online for my question. 
Thanks for help. I will close this post[Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics).

Answer (score 3):

Yes Android includes Ethernet over USB driver, and this function can be accessed by at least two ways:

(1) Adb port forwarding enabled by the following command in terminal. This requires adb being installed. Use any port number you want.

```
adb forward tcp:1234 tcp:1234
```

(2) USB tethering. It's usually found in Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> More... -> Tethering & portable hotspot -> USB tethering. If you connect your android device to a Linux computer via micro-USB cable and enable this function, your Linux computer will consider this cable as an "Ethernet" connection (actually shown as 'usb0' by ifconfig).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes.  Android has Ethernet over USB Driver. I would use  USB tethering. You can find it in Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> More... -> Tethering & portable hotspot -> USB tethering. If you connect your android device to a Linux computer via micro-USB cable.